# Necessary code changes to run server live over local

Tags: clojure, httpserver

I have never done any kind of web programming before so I have no idea what I need to do to get this Clojure app I wrote to run on live server. The url of my page is http://rowdy.msudenver.edu/~jnels124/. Here is my Clojure code

```
(ns startingclojure.core
  (:use (compojure handler[core :only (GET POST defroutes)]) 
        [clojure.pprint])
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as en]
            [ring.util.response :as response]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]))
(defonce counter (atom 10000))
(defonce urls (atom {}))
( defn shorten 
  [url]
  (let [id (swap! counter inc)
        id (Long/toString id 36)]
    (swap! urls assoc id url)
    id))

(en/deftemplate homepage
 (en/xml-resource "homepage.html") 
  [request]
  [:#listing :li] 
  (en/clone-for [[id url] @urls] 
                [:a] (comp ;; comp composes any number of functions 
                        (en/content (format "%s : %s" id, url))
                        (en/set-attr :href (str \/ id)))))                
(defn redirect 
  [id] 
  (response/redirect (@urls id)))

(defroutes app*;; * ususally means implementation detail or lower level operation
  (GET "/" request (homepage request)) 
  (POST "/shorten" request 
        (let [id (shorten (-> request :params :url))] 
         (response/redirect "/")))
  (GET "/:id" [id] (redirect id)))
(def app (compojure.handler/site app*))
```

Here is the html

```
<html>
        <head>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form method="POST" action="/shorten">
                        <input type="text" name="url"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Shorten!"/>
                </form>
                <ul id="listing">
                        <li>
                                <a href="/shorturl">id :url</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </body>
</html>
```

So here are the actual questions I have.

1. How do I get the Clojure to execute on the server. I have been loading this code in the repel and starting with `(def server(jetty/run-jetty #'app {:port 8080 :join? false}))`?
2. Also, what is the correct way to bring this project into view(i.e file structure). The file structure on the server is just 
     Top level: bin public_html
     in public_html is cgi-bin index.html startingclojure(my app, from tutorial)

in index html is what you see when that page is entered and startingclojure has the leiningen file structure.

I am not sure if I have provided the all of the necessary information but I am happy to provide anything you may need to help me get started. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Running lein, or even a repl, on a production box is a bad idea.

You should define a `-main` function that creates and runs your web server process if you execute `lein run` locally. Then, when you are ready to deploy, run `lein uberjar` to create a jar containing your entire app and all its dependencies. Once you have that jar file on the server, you can run it via `java -jar my-app.jar`. You will probably want a script that also sets up all the right java execution variables and the port it should run on etc. (these can be provided on the command line and are passed in as strings to -main).

If the app requires certain files to be unpacked, you will need to extract the jar (or at least that part of the jar) and make sure the app process can find it at runtime. A jar is a zip file, and can be extracted with the unzip command from the command line. If you need to refer to resources that are still inside the jar for reading, you should replace any references to `clojure.java.io.file` (or native java `File` objects) with `clojure.java.io/resource`.

It will probably take a while to work out all these inter-environment differences, but luckily each of these steps can be tested locally as you refine them.